# need help solving errors while creating a memory game in java

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java and am very confused about errors in my code. I have the error at line 48 "local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final". here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MemoryGame extends JFrame 
{
    private JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[4][4];
    private Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW};
    private List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int score = 0;

    public MemoryGame() 
    {
        setTitle("Memory Game");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        // populate colorList with two copies of each color
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        {
            for (Color color : colors) 
            {
                colorList.add(color);
            }
        }
        // shuffle colorList
        Collections.shuffle(colorList);

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
            {
                JButton button = new JButton();
                button.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                buttons[i][j] = button;
                add(button);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                        final int currentIndex = index;
                        JButton clickedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
                        Color color = colorList.get(currentIndex);
                        clickedButton.setBackground(color);
                        clickedButton.setEnabled(false);
                        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                        {
                            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
                            {
                                if (buttons[x][y].getBackground() == color && buttons[x][y] != clickedButton) 
                                {
                                    buttons[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                                    score++;
                                    if (score == 8) 
                                    {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MemoryGame.this, "You won!");
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            index++;
        }
    }
    setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new MemoryGame();
    }
}
```

I've tried different things to solve the error and they just result in more errors. the program is meant to have a grid of different squares that can be clicked on to display their colors and matched by the user. when the user matches all of the colors on the grid they win.

Comment: `index` can't be referenced from within your `ActionListener` as it's value changes - so what actually is the value of `index` when the `ActionListener` is triggered? What you need is a better way to look up the index value of the button.  You could use a `Map` to map the `JButton` to an `int` value; you could make use of the [`clientProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) capabilities of `JButton` to store the `index` directly against the instance of `JButton`

Comment: If the relationship between the buttons and the colors is linear, you could calculate the index of the color from based on the x/y value of the button, but you'd need to run through the button list EVERY TIME `actionPerformed` was called, which wouldn't be very efficient.  You could also make use of the `actionCommand` property of the `JButton`, but this would require you to change your color model and allow it to generate a "key" for the button which it could then use to look up the associated color, workable, just not pretty

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `final int currentIndex = index;` as the compiler was telling you in the error message. `actionPerformed` will run at some unspecified future time and the compiler has no idea what value of `index` you expect to find there at that time.

What do you want to do? Assign colors to buttons. You can do that more directly with

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
buttons[i][j] = button;
// let's store the color for later
button.putClientProperty("color", colorList.get(index));
add(button);
```

outside the handler.

And then retrieving it inside:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    JButton clickedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
    Color color = (Color)clickedButton.getClientProperty("color");
```